# Is it possible to write Android app without an SDK?

Tags: android

Just wondering, since Android apps are Java programs, would it be possible to write one entirely from scratch without using an SDK? If no, then why not?

Comment: Are you aware that the JDK by itself is an SDK?

Comment: I mean the program that would work in Android. It does not have to install via Android market, as long as it could be installed on rooted phone.

Comment: What I mean is to write a Java program using something like Eclipse but not using official Android SDK, just like you would write any regular Java program. Maybe using Swing, maybe SWT, something like that...

Comment: @Dmitri: I doubt that. There is no such thing as Swing in Android. It *could* be possible, if you restrained yourself to things available under both Android and the JDK, which would be very limiting. And even then, it might not be doable (some Android expert will have to say).

Comment: Why negative vote? Was that not a good questions?

Comment: Well, I may as well point out that TECHNICALLY no, you don't NEED anything specific to write a program in ANY language. If you (somehow) knew every single thing about that language and knew it inside and out, backwards and forwards, than it would be "possible" to write the entire thing in a simple text editor. Ha, but the difficulty of this is about a 50 on a scale of 1-10. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Android apps are coded in Java- but only a subset of the standard Java API is included, and even that has a few custom modifications. Whilst the first stage of compiliation to a .apk file is to compile to Java bytecode, Android then has to convert that into Dalvik bytecode and package, sign, and zip align your application to make it run. In addition the SDK will handle generating necessary files like R.java and your xml that the ordinary Java compilers won't know how to handle.

So whilst you can easily code your entire project just using notepad, compilation will need the Android SDK.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to the SDK? Is there a Makefile that generates these R.java and XML metadata, or a way to foist the Dalvik conversion on the end device itself or use LLVM for it? Or are we really stuck with this [proprietary](http://archive.is/GmMjm#selection-509.1215-509.1255) SDK as an **immutable** part of the build chain for a [supposedly open-source](http://archive.is/OsG2c#selection-1773.13-1773.55) platform?

Comment: “As an open source project, Android's goal is to avoid any central point of failure in which one industry player can restrict or control the innovations of any other player.” ⸻ “You may not use [The Android Software Development Kit] to develop applications for other platforms…[or] for any purpose not expressly permitted by [this] License Agreement…[including to] modify, adapt, redistribute, decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble…any part of the SDK. Google may stop [providing any aspect of] the SDK at Google's sole discretion.…”

Answer (score 3):

You couldn't do it as you need the Android-specific classes that are part of the SDK.  Not to mention the useful tools for creating the package (packing, signing, etc.) and other odds and sods.