# Is it possible to build an android apk without using SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk, ide

I'm pushing `app` folder and `gradle` files to git. The purpose is to build an apk file without IDE. It is achieved by
 - installing `gradle`
 - executing `gradle` commands from terminal

But it requires the `local.properties` file which includes the sdk path of my local system.

Is there any way to build an `apk` or run `gradle` without involving `sdk`

Docs says

> Applications are usually developed in Java programming language using the Android software development kit (SDK), but other development environments are also available.

what are the other environments? How do I use it?

> the development of an Android application requires an SDK with Java, for iOS apps an iOS SDK with Swift, and for MS Windows the .NET Framework SDK with .NET. There are also SDKs that are installed in apps to provide analytics and data about activity. Prominent examples include Google, InMobi and Facebook.

If I've to build an apk without IDE, I need the source code and gradle software. Do I need sdk as a mandatory? or could it be replaced? If yes How?

I've searched for the same, but guess it is not possible without sdk. Am I wrong? Kindly Help.

Comment: “or could it be replaced? If yes How?” I share this question, and find it extremely disturbing that there's apparently no discussion online _about_ this (aside from this very post)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to build an Android app without using SDK. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4933207/4432988). If you want to build an app without using an IDE though you can read about it for example [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline) and [here](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676).

Answer (score -1):

You can't create android apk file without having android sdk. Install the android studio from official google site.

Comment: I do have Android studio. But the aim is do it without IDE. I'm looking for any replacement to sdk